# Postgres - using `ARRAY_AGG()` aggregate function in multiple cases for same array

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, array-agg

I am trying to write an **SQL** query using `CASE` where I want to return the values from the `campaign` table of the selected row when on two cases:

1. The current time is between the start date and end date, which is displayed in the query.
   *That part is working as expected and is included in the provided example.*
2. WHERE `publish_end_at`  is `null`. *This is what I am trying to implement.*

My query:

```
CASE
    WHEN publish_queue.message_id IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        (
         SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) FROM campaign WHERE react_to_publish_queue_id = publish_queue.id
         AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN publish_start_at AND publish_end_at)
        )
     ELSE '{}'
 END AS running,
 CASE
     WHEN publish_queue.message_id IS NOT NULL
     THEN
         (
           SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) FROM campaign WHERE react_to_publish_queue_id = publish_queue.id 
           AND publish_start_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     ELSE '{}'
 END AS published,
```

Basically, I mean that if `publish_end_at` is `null` and `publish_start_at` is *less than a minute older* than the **current timestamp**, it should appear in the **running**. If it’s more than a minute, it should appear in the published.

I do not know how to define this part of the query in the already defined one which I provided an example. Should I use `OR` operator inside the aggregate function `ARRAY_AGG()` or I can do it differently?

There are two tables just for the sake of the representation of data:

Here is `publish_queue` table:

| id | team_member_id | message_id | campaign_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1859001 | 8566 | 1171 | 51543 |

`campaign` table:

| id | team_member_id | publish_start_at | publish_end_at | react_to_publish_queue_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8566 | 2022-05-30 09:19:00 | null | 1859001 |

The output would be:

```
"running_status": [
    2,
    ...
]
```

Can someone please help, I am pretty new to writing complex cases. Thanks

Comment: I think you lost identifier naming consistency in one of the edits before publishing the question - there's no `status_end_at` outside your first paragraph. *"publish_start_at is less than a minute older than the current timestamp"* this would translate to `publish_start_at between current_timestamp-'1 minute' and current_timestamp` which I don't see either

Comment: Thanks for replay. I edited the post, it was a typo, I thought of publish_end_at. I would define it like: The examples I already have are the ones where publish_end_at are set and I need to import one more WHERE publish_end_at will be null. @Zegarek

Comment: I meant that we do not cover both cases. One is where it is BETWEEN start and end time (that one is where publish_end_at is not null) and the other where publish_end_at is null. @Zegarek

Comment: Another attempt, to see if I understand it right: **1. running**: `publish_end_at` is not known but `publish_start_at` was less than a minute ago **OR** we're currently between `publish_start_at` and a known `publish_end_at`. **2. published**: `publish_end_at` unknown but `publish_start_at` was more than a minute ago **OR** we're currently past a known `publish_end_at` timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that's the case! Thanks, you helped a lot. :) @Zegarek

Comment: I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74613093/5298879) with these assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these conditions:

1. Status **`running`**:

   - `publish_end_at` is not known but `publish_start_at` was less than a minute ago

   **OR**

   - we're currently between `publish_start_at` and a
     known `publish_end_at`.
2. Status **`published`**:

   - `publish_end_at` unknown but `publish_start_at` was more than a
     minute ago

   **OR**

   - we're currently past a known `publish_end_at`
     timestamp.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN publish_queue.message_id IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) 
         FROM campaign 
         WHERE react_to_publish_queue_id = publish_queue.id
         AND (   (    publish_end_at IS null
                  AND publish_start_at BETWEEN now()-'1 minute'::interval AND now() 
                 )
              OR (    publish_end_at IS NOT null
                  AND now() BETWEEN publish_start_at AND publish_end_at 
                 ) 
             )
        )
     ELSE '{}'
 END AS running,
 CASE
     WHEN publish_queue.message_id IS NOT NULL
     THEN
        (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) 
         FROM campaign 
         WHERE react_to_publish_queue_id = publish_queue.id
         AND (   (    publish_end_at IS null
                  AND publish_start_at < now()-'1 minute'::interval 
                 )
              OR (    publish_end_at IS NOT null
                  AND now() > publish_end_at  
                 )
             )
        )
     ELSE '{}'
 END AS published,
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7Ko1wYYJ)

Comment: I tested the code and what needs to be done is to add an INTERVAL like NOW() - INTERVAL '1 minute' so it does not throw a syntax error. However, when I input the current timestamp into databases publish_start_at it is always published.. I am not sure why is that..? @Zegarek

Comment: Good catch, I've added the type casts. `now()+'1 minute'` works without the `::interval` because of how `+` operator is defined: PostgreSQL can deduce that if the first argument is a `timestamptz`, the second can only be an `interval`. For `-`, the second can be either an `interval` or `timestamp`(tz), so a cast is required to select the variant. I overlooked that.

Comment: As to why everything fell into **`published`** category, we'd have to take a look at some samples and a fully working query. You can set up a small demo on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30), with minimal amount of anonymised/obfuscated/non-production data (e.g. real timestamps, fake ids).

Comment: I've added it. Can you please check: https://dbfiddle.uk/VxIaRLH3 @Zegarek

Comment: After some corrections to make the demo work, it seems to be fine. I added some test cases [Updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/a8PcGsqS)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to me that you did not change anything when I compared with an SQL in posted answer. Right? @Zegarek

Comment: I corrected the answer to use `::interval` casting, as you pointed out. Your `interval '...'` in the demo is just alternative syntax, same as `'...'::interval`. In the demo I posted back, I changed the formatting, column types, quoted the `text`-based ID and added test cases. [Updated demo, once more.](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9GgVvsX) - in this one you have clear cases

Comment: Ah, I see now. You are really a lifesaver. I saved this post so I can learn from it and apply on other examples. Thanks again. @Zegarek